# How to find maximum value in Pandas data frame and assign a new Value to it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my pandas data frame pandas data frame

```
ID          Position   Time(in Hours) Date
01          18          2             01/01/2016
01          21          4             01/10/2016
01          19          2             01/10/2016
05          19          5             01/10/2016
05          21          1             01/10/2016
05          19          8             01/10/2016
02          19          18            02/10/2016
02          35          11            02/10/2016
```

I need to assign '1' for the maximum Time for each Id and Date else assign '0'. 
My code is

```
def find_max(db7):
max_row = db7['Time'].max()
labels = np.where((db7['Time_in_Second'] == max_row),'1','0')
return max_row

db7['Max'] = db7['Time'].map(find_max)
```

But I'm getting below error. How do I do this please?

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

My Expected out put should be:

```
ID          Position   Time(in Hours) Date        Max
01          18          2             01/01/2016  0
01          21          4             01/10/2016  1
01          19          2             01/10/2016  0
05          19          5             01/10/2016  0
05          21          1             01/10/2016  0
05          19          8             01/10/2016  1
02          19          18            02/10/2016  1
02          35          11            02/10/2016  0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `max` and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for assign new values:

```
max1 = db7.groupby(['ID','Date'])['Time(in Hours)'].transform('max')
db7['Max'] = np.where(db7['Time(in Hours)'].eq(max1), '1', '0')
print (db7)
   ID  Position  Time(in Hours)        Date Max
0   1        18               2  01/01/2016   1
1   1        21               4  01/10/2016   1
2   1        19               2  01/10/2016   0
3   5        19               5  01/10/2016   0
4   5        21               1  01/10/2016   0
5   5        19               8  01/10/2016   1
6   2        19              18  02/10/2016   1
7   2        35              11  02/10/2016   0
```

Or convert `True`s and `False`s to  `'1'` and `'0'` by double `astype`:

```
max1 = db7.groupby(['ID','Date'])['Time(in Hours)'].transform('max')
db7['Max'] = db7['Time(in Hours)'].eq(max1).astype(int).astype(str)
print (db7)
   ID  Position  Time(in Hours)        Date  Max
0   1        18               2  01/01/2016    1
1   1        21               4  01/10/2016    1
2   1        19               2  01/10/2016    0
3   5        19               5  01/10/2016    0
4   5        21               1  01/10/2016    0
5   5        19               8  01/10/2016    1
6   2        19              18  02/10/2016    1
7   2        35              11  02/10/2016    0
```

Detail:

```
print (max1)
0     2
1     4
2     4
3     8
4     8
5     8
6    18
7    18
Name: Time(in Hours), dtype: int64

#eq is same as ==
print (db7['Time(in Hours)'].eq(max1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: Time(in Hours), dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

If need group by only column `ID`:

```
max1 = db7.groupby('ID')['Time(in Hours)'].transform('max')
db7['Max'] = np.where(db7['Time(in Hours)'].eq(max1), '1', '0')
print (db7)
   ID  Position  Time(in Hours)        Date Max
0   1        18               2  01/01/2016   0
1   1        21               4  01/10/2016   1
2   1        19               2  01/10/2016   0
3   5        19               5  01/10/2016   0
4   5        21               1  01/10/2016   0
5   5        19               8  01/10/2016   1
6   2        19              18  02/10/2016   1
7   2        35              11  02/10/2016   0

print (max1)
0     4
1     4
2     4
3     8
4     8
5     8
6    18
7    18
Name: Time(in Hours), dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please I added my expected out put. In your results it wouldn't be get "1" for first row? Because when we compare very first three rows the Max value will be 4 (for Time in Hours).

Comment: Then use `max1 = db7.groupby('ID'['Time(in Hours)'].transform('max')` - group by column `ID` only.

Comment: Yeah its fine. Thanks